# How to generate gcc debug symbol outside the build target?

Tags: gcc, debugging, pdb-files

I know I can generate debug symbol using -g option. However the symbol is embeded in the target file. Could gcc generate debug symbol outside the result executable/library? Like .pdb file of windows VC++ compiler did.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

You need to use *objcopy* to [separate the debug information](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html):

```
objcopy --only-keep-debug "${tostripfile}" "${debugdir}/${debugfile}"
strip --strip-debug --strip-unneeded "${tostripfile}"
objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink="${debugdir}/${debugfile}" "${tostripfile}"
```

I use the bash script below to separate the debug information into files with a .debug extension in a .debug directory. This way I can tar the libraries and executables in one tar file and the .debug directories in another. If I want to add the debug info later on I simply extract the debug tar file and voila I have symbolic debug information.

This is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

scriptdir=`dirname ${0}`
scriptdir=`(cd ${scriptdir}; pwd)`
scriptname=`basename ${0}`

set -e

function errorexit()
{
  errorcode=${1}
  shift
  echo $@
  exit ${errorcode}
}

function usage()
{
  echo "USAGE ${scriptname} <tostrip>"
}

tostripdir=`dirname "$1"`
tostripfile=`basename "$1"`


if [ -z ${tostripfile} ] ; then
  usage
  errorexit 0 "tostrip must be specified"
fi

cd "${tostripdir}"

debugdir=.debug
debugfile="${tostripfile}.debug"

if [ ! -d "${debugdir}" ] ; then
  echo "creating dir ${tostripdir}/${debugdir}"
  mkdir -p "${debugdir}"
fi
echo "stripping ${tostripfile}, putting debug info into ${debugfile}"
objcopy --only-keep-debug "${tostripfile}" "${debugdir}/${debugfile}"
strip --strip-debug --strip-unneeded "${tostripfile}"
objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink="${debugdir}/${debugfile}" "${tostripfile}"
chmod -x "${debugdir}/${debugfile}"
```

Comment: If you have a problem in production and need to attach the process with gdb, will you be able to provide the debug symbol file to GDB? And how, if so ? thnx

Comment: @yves Baumes Just add the .debug directory with the .debug files to your production box and GDB should pick them up. After the debug session you can remove them again.

Comment: Refer @Lance Richardson answer comments for an example.

Comment: Is it also possible to restore the original binary (e.g. stripped binary + .debug file = original binary) ?

Comment: Do you find any problems with omitting [`--build-id` linker option](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html)?

Comment: `putting debug info into ${debugfile}` should probably be `putting debug info into ${debugdir}/${debugfile}`. I was confused why was I not finding *.debg file, turns out the script puts it in debugdir, which is not mentioned in the print.

Answer (score 158):

**Compile with debug information:**

```
gcc -g -o main main.c
```

**Separate the debug information:**

```
objcopy --only-keep-debug main main.debug
```

or

```
cp main main.debug
strip --only-keep-debug main.debug
```

**Strip debug information from origin file:**

```
objcopy --strip-debug main
```

or

```
strip --strip-debug --strip-unneeded main
```

**debug by debuglink mode:**

```
objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink main.debug main
gdb main
```

**You can also use exec file and symbol file separatly:**

```
gdb -s main.debug -e main
```

or

```
gdb
(gdb) exec-file main
(gdb) symbol-file main.debug
```

**For details:**

```
(gdb) help exec-file
(gdb) help symbol-file
```

Ref:
https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html#Files
https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html

Comment: And you should use ```objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink main main.debug``` to embed the name of the created debug file and a checksum. In this case gdb will try to find the debug code itself in a few distribution depended locations, no -s option is needed anymore.

Answer (score 16):

No answer so far mentions `eu-strip --strip-debug -f <out.debug> <input>`.

- This is provided by `elfutils` package.
- The result will be that `<input>` file has been stripped of debug symbols which are now all in `<out.debug>`.

Answer (score 9):

Check out the "--only-keep-debug" option of the [strip](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/strip.html) command.

From the link:

> The intention is that this option will be used in conjunction with --add-gnu-debuglink to create a two part executable. One a stripped binary which will occupy less space in RAM and in a distribution and the second a debugging information file which is only needed if debugging abilities are required.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it:
gcc -ggdb -o test test.c;
cp test test.debug;
strip --only-keep-debug test.debug;
strip test;
objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=test.debug test;
Then it's ok to debug test

Answer (score 9):

NOTE: Programs compiled with high-optimization levels (-O3, -O4) cannot generate many debugging symbols for optimized variables, in-lined functions and unrolled loops, regardless of the symbols being embedded (-g) or extracted (objcopy) into a '.debug' file.

Alternate approaches are

1. Embed the versioning (VCS, git, svn) data into the program, for compiler optimized executables (-O3, -O4).
2. Build a 2nd non-optimized version of the executable.

The first option provides a means to rebuild the production code with full debugging and symbols at a later date.  Being able to re-build the original production code with no optimizations is a tremendous help for debugging.  (NOTE: This assumes testing was done with the optimized version of the program).

Your build system can create a .c file loaded with the compile date, commit, and other VCS details.  Here is a 'make + git' example:

```
program: program.o version.o 

program.o: program.cpp program.h 

build_version.o: build_version.c    

build_version.c: 
    @echo "const char *build1=\"VCS: Commit: $(shell git log -1 --pretty=%H)\";" > "$@"
    @echo "const char *build2=\"VCS: Date: $(shell git log -1 --pretty=%cd)\";" >> "$@"
    @echo "const char *build3=\"VCS: Author: $(shell git log -1 --pretty="%an %ae")\";" >> "$@"
    @echo "const char *build4=\"VCS: Branch: $(shell git symbolic-ref HEAD)\";" >> "$@"
    # TODO: Add compiler options and other build details

.TEMPORARY: build_version.c
```

After the program is compiled you can locate the original 'commit' for your code by using the command: `strings -a my_program | grep VCS`

```
VCS: PROGRAM_NAME=my_program
VCS: Commit=190aa9cace3b12e2b58b692f068d4f5cf22b0145
VCS: BRANCH=refs/heads/PRJ123_feature_desc
VCS: AUTHOR=Joe Developer  joe.developer@somewhere.com
VCS: COMMIT_DATE=2013-12-19
```

All that is left is to check-out the original code, re-compile without optimizations, and start debugging.

Comment: `-O4` doesn't even exist.

Comment: Oops, that may be from may 'suncc' days, where '-O5' was even an option.  Here's a link to the gcc4.4.7  -O options: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.7/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options

Comment: This does not address the common problem of trying to interpret a core dump that may not be easily reproducible. The advice in this answer is sound, *but* it does not address the question.