# The best Linux tool for disassembling C++ executables

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, disassembly

Which tool is the best for disassembling C++ executables? I'm looking for something like OllyDbg but for Linux.

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to tell that I want to be able to debug, too, not just to see the asm code.

EDIT2: By "best" I mean something like - "the best for windows is OllyDbg - can see the asm code and can debug, it's user friendly and very powerful. Which one is best for Linux".

Comment: does gdb (disas command) work or you need more?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237489/how-can-i-force-gdb-to-disassemble

Comment: I guess "best" requires some more explanation. What are the requirements? Disassembling alone is possible via `objdump -Cd` (part of the GNU binutils). But it isn't a debugger.

Comment: Well, I'm new to this( disassembling, and to Linux even) , so I don't know how exactly to explain what I mean by "the best". It's something like - "the best for windows is OllyDbg - user friendly and very powerful. Which one is best for Linux". Something like this..

Comment: Argh, yeah. Sorry, I missed that - not only disassebmler, but debugger, too.. That's why I mentioned OllyDbg. Sorry again, my bad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some. Good luck with your debugging!

[UPS Debugger](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ups/)

[Evan's Debugger](http://freshmeat.net/projects/edebugger/)

[Assembly Language Debugger (ALD)](http://ald.sourceforge.net/)

[Insight](http://sources.redhat.com/insight/)

[Data Display Debugger (ddd)](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd)

[AsmBug](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asmbug/)

[Dissy](http://code.google.com/p/dissy/)

Comment: Thanks! What's your favorite ?

Comment: I im used to the bastard dissassembler http://bastard.sourceforge.net/. You want something close to Olly so i suggest you can try Evan's Debugger

Comment: Thanks, Reno! Evan's Debugger sounds great to me(I just visited the link, you posted here).

Answer (score 1):

If gcc was used to compile, you can use `objdump`
Can be used on a single `.o` file, a library or even a full executable.

Comment: Argh, sorry, my bad. Forgot to tell that I want a tool, that's able to debug, too, like OllyDbg. And I've used gdb to debug, but debug core files or to debug my own code. I want a tool, that would help me for reverse engineering. Thanks and sorry for not being comprehensive

Comment: Ah, I understand.  I would recommend gdb then, it is certainly able to debug in assembly mode.  However, because it's a pain in the ass for even normal debugging, I won't.

Comment: What do you think about Evan's debugger? Or you haven't used it. Thanks :)

Comment: It looks ok, but I haven't used it.