# Why I can't disassemble this user space address?

Tags: gdb, shared-libraries

```
Dump of assembler code for function foo@plt:
0x0000000000400528 <foo@plt+0>: jmpq   *0x2004d2(%rip)        # 0x600a00 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+40>
0x000000000040052e <foo@plt+6>: pushq  $0x2
0x0000000000400533 <foo@plt+11>:    jmpq   0x4004f8
(gdb) disas 0x4004f8
No function contains specified address.
```

I knwo `0x4004f8` is the entry point of procedure linkage table,but why I can't `disas` it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`disas` with one address needs to find the function the address is contained within to know how much to disassemble.

Either with `disas` with two arguments, or `x/i`.

Also see:
[How can I force GDB to disassemble?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237489/how-can-i-force-gdb-to-disassemble)

Comment: the plt is used to resolve dynamically linked `function`,what about dynamic `variable`?

Comment: Also,how can `0x4004f8` not be contained in any function? There should always be a function that wraps this address IMO...

Comment: 0x4004f8 is probably in a function, but gdb can't understand it for some reason. Give gdb a range and have done with it?

Comment: Yes it works ,but I want to investigate more about how shared library works(especially how variables in it are referenced),do you want a separate thread for this ? :)

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a different question to me.