# How can I print instructions before (previous) the current instruction pointer using gdb?

Tags: linux, gdb

How can I print instructions before (previous) the current instruction pointer using gdb linux ?

Answer (score 3):

On processors with fixed instruction length (e.g. `SPARC`) it's very easy:

```
(gdb) disas $pc-40,$pc+1
```

On `x86_64`, the same approach works, with one caveat: `$pc-40` may "land" in the middle of instruction, and you would get "garbage" for the first few instructions. However, *usually* the disassembly re-synchronizes and the tail of the output is correct. Rarely it doesn't, and then you have to try `$pc-41` or `$pc-42`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Machine Code](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Machine-Code.html#Machine-Code) section of the GDB documentation, when you specify arguments to the `disassemble` command you can use `$pc` in an expression, e.g.

```
disas $pc-8, $pc
```

Answer (score 1):

In GDB, you can use `x /<N>i $pc` to disassemble a number of instructions from the current program counter. Luckily, N can be any number, including negatives, so, with N as -1, you get the previous instruction:

```
>>> x /-1i $pc
   0x8001040 <main>:    xor    %eax,%eax
```

For context (the program counter is at the line that starts with `=>`):

```
>>> disas
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000008001040 <+0>:     xor    %eax,%eax
=> 0x0000000008001042 <+2>:     ret
End of assembler dump.
```

**NOTE:** You must compile with line number information, i.e.: `gcc -g`

Unlike the other replies, this works even if you don't know the size of the previous instruction.

Reference: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html