Unable to investigate core dump if binary is compiled with -pie option
I am using Buildroot to build an application for my ARMv5 board. Everything worked just fine before I've upgraded Buildroot to newer version, which by default has PIE/PIC feature enabled (PIE = Position-Independent Executables, PIC = Position-Independent Code).
GCC options:
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-fstack-protector-strong' '-fPIE' '-pie' '--version' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mcpu=arm926ej-s' '-mfloat-abi=soft' '-mabi=aapcs-linux' '-marm' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-march=armv5tej'

Some of flags used as GCC parameters:
 -std=c++17 -Wno-psabi -Wno-deprecated-copy -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -pipe -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Wextra -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wno-write-strings 
 -pthread -funwind-tables -rdynamic -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -ggdb  -D'UNUSED_PARAM(x)=x' -Werror   -Os -g2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -Os

The board runs stripped binary and I use non-stripped one to load debug symbols. Output of file command on non-stripped binary:
ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, for GNU/Linux 4.15.0, with debug_info, not stripped

.gdbinit file:
set verbose on
set auto-load safe-path /
set sysroot /home/user/buildroot/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot

GDB output:
$ output/host/usr/bin/arm-linux-gdb output/build/App-master/build/src/App core.App.08_21_2024_11.50.31

GNU gdb (GDB) 9.2
...
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi".
...
Reading symbols from output/build/App-master/build/src/App...
Reading in symbols for ../../src/main.cc...done.
[New LWP 896]
[New LWP 898]
[New LWP 900]
[New LWP 901]
[New LWP 904]
[New LWP 906]
[New LWP 907]
[New LWP 908]
[New LWP 911]
[New LWP 912]

warning: platform-specific solib_create_inferior_hook did not load initial shared libraries.
Core was generated by `/usr/bin/App -arg'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0xb601f450 in ?? ()
[Current thread is 1 (LWP 896)]

(gdb) bt
#0  0xb601f450 in ?? ()
#1  0xfffffffe in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
* 1    LWP 896           0xb601f450 in ?? ()
  2    LWP 898           0xb6159990 in ?? ()
  3    LWP 900           0xb608e278 in ?? ()
  4    LWP 901           0xb60cbb60 in ?? ()
  5    LWP 904           0xb6159990 in ?? ()
  6    LWP 906           0xb608e278 in ?? ()
  7    LWP 907           0xb6159db0 in ?? ()
  8    LWP 908           0xb615e824 in ?? ()
  9    LWP 911           0xb60cbb60 in ?? ()
  10   LWP 912           0xb60cbb60 in ?? ()

(gdb) info sharedlibrary 
No shared libraries loaded at this time.

If I manually disable PIE, everything works as before, I am able to see stack trace normally. Also, when I'm building the same application for different board (Raspberry Pi 4), stack trace works even with PIE enabled.
Any ideas how to make it work without disabling PIE?

-g is missed in GCC flags. -pie is irrelevant.

During actual compilation there are more flags passed to gcc. Added them to post. -g2 is actually passed. file command also shows that debug symbols are present.

I think you have a similar issue with a core as I had with cross debug.   So the idea is that you need to recreate a PC binary with symbols located at the relocated address.  There could be some other way to do this, but the main issue is the host gdb has no information on where the binary was relocated to.  symbol-file with an offset may work in your case.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237489/how-to-disassemble-a-memory-range-with-gdb/73367165#73367165

I suspect the reason the RPi is working is the Linux and tooling versions.  You never gave info on that.  Try finding info on 'kernel, gdb, gcc/g++, and binutils' versions and compare.
