# Given program counter, find the source line in a shared library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, objdump

I'm trying to debug a segfault in Android's surfaceflinger daemon on a custom made ARM board. The process crashes before dumping the call stack and register content, including the program counter.

Normally I would've used objdump and searched for the program counter. The problem is that part of the call stack is in a shared library. Without using gdb, how can I correlate the program counter with a line in the source file? That is, can the addresses of shared library instructions be determined without running the program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution is to load core dump into gdb and use `info symbol <program counter address>`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7648883/72178.

You can also use `addr2line` but you will have to provide library starting address in parameters to `addr2line`, see [How to map function address to function in *.so files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7556045/72178).

Answer (score 2):

You need your program (and all the relevant shared libraries) to be compiled with debug information (in [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) format), e.g. by passing some `-g` (or `-g2` or `-g3`) flag to the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler when they are built. Notice that with GCC such a debugging option can be mixed with optimization options like `-O2`

Then you might use utilities like [addr2line](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/addr2line.html), or perhaps libraries like [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace). FWIW, the GCC compiler itself (actually its `cc1plus`) uses that `libbacktrace` library to print a useful backtrace on `SIGSEGV` and other terminating signals (on compiler crashes).

BTW, you could (and probably should) enable [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) dumping and do a post mortem analysis of it with `gdb`

Notice that due to [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), a shared library is loaded (actually [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)-ed) at some "random" page.

Read Drepper's [*How to Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper.