# Are using a debugger and heavy usage of C++ templates incompatible in the long run?

Tags: c++, debugging, templates, gdb, g++

I'm working on a project that uses a lot of templates and libraries like boost:: fusion and found myself struggling with an executable that, as of today, is 600MB and gdb needs 1.7 GB of memory to just load it, and a symbol lookup would make it use nearly 3GBs..
The stripped binary is about 5 MBs.

The question is, is there anything to be done in order to generate smaller debug symbols? This is not only a problem with gdb but also with the linker, which uses another 1.2 GB of RAM when linking objects compiled with the -g flag

I've tried -g1 -g2 and -g3 and the problem remains the same.

Comment: Tell us something more about your program. What does it do and what is suppose to be doing....

Comment: gcc lacks something equivalent to comdat folding last I checked.  And symbol name compression would probably also help.

Comment: I think your problem is the 600MB executable (seriously, wtf?), not gcc/gdb's (in)ability to compress debug symbols.

Comment: Most modern IDEs and debuggers deal with template code just fine.

Comment: Maybe you just use an old gcc version. I've been in a similar situation at some point in a specific company, we "upgraded" to gcc4.5 and even if with debug flags the application was 500mo, with optimizations it was close to 2 mo. The application also used tons of metaprogramming. GCC got better at these with time, so check your version.

Comment: No, this happens with current gcc versions, from gcc-4.5 upsto 4.8. The program has huge symbols because of template metaprogramming, nested templates and using boost::fusion

Comment: Well, I routinely debug core-dumps that weigh between 1.5GB and 2GB, and require loading ~100 libraries of a couple MB each, and gdb deals with those without issue (though initial load time might be a bit long). So, is the issue about gdb, or about an under-sized machine ?

Comment: Matthieu, yours is a different case, I'm not talking about loading a core dump. And it's not a problem with an under sized machine, but with scalability of the project, since the usage of ram of gdb and ld increase faster than hardware upgrades allow

Answer (score 2):

> is there anything to be done in order to generate smaller debug
>   symbols?

You can use GNU gold linker with `--compress-debug-sections=zlib` option instead of default ld linker to compress output debug symbols. Gdb supports compressed debug sections since 7.0 version.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know the gold linker, but I got "collect2: error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault], core dumped" when I tried using it. (version 2.23 from Ubuntu 13.10 repositories). I will try compiling latest version.

Comment: Nope, compiled latest version (2.24) from source and it's still coredumping when using the --compress-debug-sections=zlib flag

Comment: @Gustavo I'm also having gold segfault when trying --compress-debug-sections=zlib. Were you ever able to get this to work? Do you know if there is a bug report for gold?

Comment: @acm no, sorry, I didn't try it again.

Answer (score 1):

As a partial solution you can compile with `-g` option only few source files. Or use `strip` utility on .o-files that do not need to be debugged yet.

If the issue is just the executable file size, you can use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866721/how-to-generate-gcc-debug-symbol-outside-the-build-target) to make it smaller without loosing debug info.