# How to move gcc debug symbols outside from .so and .a files?

Tags: c++, gcc, .a, objcopy

as far as I know, `objcopy` is able to move debug symbols (compiled with -g flag) outside from an executable binary. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866721/how-to-generate-gcc-debug-symbol-outside-the-build-target), but there are only generic methods for symbol outsourcing.

But what can I do when my executable is using some really large .so and .a files?

I would like to profile my application in a small environment where is not enough place for the debug symbols. The entire project was built with -g option. The debug symbols are needed later only when the profile log is processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [strip](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strip) debug symbols:

```
strip --strip-debug object.so
```

Comment: I tried it: `strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file`

Comment: If you are compiling for an embedded system, you have to run the target version of strip, not the host one.