# Debug information file conventions for Red Hat/Fedora?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, redhat, lldb

According to lothar's answer at [How to generate gcc debug symbol outside the build target](https://stackoverflow.com/q/866721), I can create a two part executable - the stripped executable and the debug information file.

After creating the stripped executable and the debug information file, I install the executable as normal (with `make install`). But I'm not sure what to do with the debug information file for Red Hat/Fedora.

I have two questions related to debugging the executable with GDB or LLDB (if debugging is needed):

- What is the name of the debug information file on Red Hat/Fedora? Is there a convention to follow so the debugger associates them with the executable automatically?
- Where do I place the the debug information file on Red Hat/Fedora? What is the location so the debugger finds them when debugging the executable?

Here's a related question for a different platform: [Debug information file conventions for Debian/Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28787534) It would also be helpful to know the same for OS X since I work on it on occasion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Debuginfo Packaging page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Debuginfo) in the Fedora wiki discusses the generation (or lack thereof) of the `-debuginfo` subpackage when creating a RPM package, but it also includes some information about the debuginfo itself. In short, the debug symbols should be placed under `/usr/lib/debug` and the source under `/usr/src/debug`. Reading the script named in that page (`/usr/lib/rpm/find-debuginfo.sh` found in the `rpm-build` package) will give more insight.