# Separate symbols for C++ application

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I have C++ application compiled in Release mode. If it drops core dump, I would like to examine it, but this version doesn't have any symbols. Is it possible to prepare some kind of symbol file which later will be used when viewing such core dump?

Comment: Your compiled binary should have the symbols. And the same binary will be used to analyze the core dump. Compile the code with -g option in g++ to generate the symbol table with all the required symbols.

Comment: @RamandeepPunia My application is running on production, it must be compiled without symbols.

Comment: you need to have a binary with debug symbols when you build a binary for release..so you will have two binaries one for prod w/o symbols and one with symbols...when you get the core dump you can use this binary with symbols to debug

Comment: Found this topic which solved my problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866721/how-to-generate-gcc-debug-symbol-outside-the-build-target