# Separating out symbols and stripping unneeded symbols at the same time

Tags: debug-symbols, objcopy

I am interested in creating an external symbol file which I reference from my ELF file using `objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=...`.

Now I know how to extract *only* the debug symbols (`objcopy --only-keep-debug`) and how to *only* strip the debug symbols (`objcopy --strip-debug`).

However, I'd like to strip **all unneeded symbols**. I know this can be done via `objcopy --strip-unneeded`. The fact that debug and unneeded symbols are two different categories and two different command line switches suggests that there could be non-overlapping symbols.

Since unneeded symbols seem to encompass *more* than just the debug symbols, I'm afraid to lose some symbolic information when doing this (in GNU make):

```
stripped/%: %
    objcopy --only-keep-debug $@ $@.dbg
    objcopy --strip-unneeded $@
    objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=$@.dbg $@
```

Can anyone explain what kind of symbols may be removed via `--strip-unneeded` that may not be removed with `--strip-debug`? Or put differently: which symbols not kept in the external symbol file by `--only-keep-debug` may get lost when running `--strip-unneeded` on the original binary? Is there a way to retain these symbols in my external symbol file or is this a non-issue?

Goal is to be able to debug issues using the external debug symbols and not ending up missing some symbolic information and find out too late. So I don't want to lose symbolic information, I just want to remove it entirely from the program binary.

PS: I am aware of [How to generate gcc debug symbol outside the build target?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/866721/476371) But that question and its answers don't touch the detail I am asking about.

Comment: I found [this article](https://www.technovelty.org/linux/stripping-shared-libraries.html) which has some useful information. Maybe even answers the question.

Comment: @mshildt: indeed useful. Thanks. Unfortunately it does not answer the question, which is which symbols might get lost if I extract only the debug symbols into an external file and then use `--strip-unneeded` on the original file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've just stumbled to the very same question.
Previously I just separated my built ELF-binaries with the objcopy's `--only-keep-debug`, `--strip-debug`, `--add-gnu-debuglink` flags.
Now I need to save even more space and so I'm considering using `--strip-unneeded` instead of `--strip-debug`.
But like you I'm afraid that this may affect my debugging experience.

So, I've made several tests and come to the following conclusions:

1. `--strip-unneeded` strips what is stripped by `--strip-debug` and even more. I.e. 'debug' info is considered as a part of 'unneeded' info.
2. Debug binaries created with the `--only-keep-debug` flag, not only store info stripped by the `--strip-debug`, but also info stripped by the `--strip-unneeded`.
3. I've **not** noticed any difference in debugging against `--strip-debug` vs `--strip-unneeded`, provided the debug binaries created with the `--only-keep-debug`.

Details below:

I've created a very simple C++ project, which contains an executable and a shared library.
The library contains a globally exported function, which is called by the application.
Also the library contains several local functions (i.e. static or in the anonymous namespace), being called by the globally exported function. The code in the local functions just created a crash by just throwing an unhandled exception.

First, I've compiled both binaries with the `-g -O0` flags.
Second, I've extracted the debug information from them in a separate binaries and linked these debug files to the original binaries. I.e., for both files:

```
objcopy --only-keep-debug $FILE $FILE.debug
objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=$FILE.debug $FILE
```

After this point I had unstripped binaries also having separate correspondent linked debug binaries.

Then I've copied these files into two additional directories. In the first one I've done `--strip-debug` against the original binaries and in another I've done `--strip-unneeded`.

Considering file sizes, the original files where obviously the biggest, the files in strip-unneeded dir where the smallest, and the files in the strip-debug dir were in the middle.
Also, additionally running `--strip-debug` against the files in the strip-unneeded dir has not changed the file sizes, meaning that `--strip-debug` strips just some subset of what is stripped by `--strip-unneeded`.

I've then compared section listing of all the three variants by running `readelf -S` against all of them.
Looking at them, it could be seen that `--strip-debug` strips the following sections: `.debug_arranges`, `.debug_info`, `.debug_abbrev`, `.debug_line` and `.debug_str`, and also somewhat reduced the `.symtab` and `.strtab` sections.
`--strip-unneeded` also additionally completely removes `.symtab` and `.strtab` sections.

I've then run `readelf -S` against the debug binaries, which I'd got with the `--only-keep-debug` flag. The sections there had all the sections removed by `--strip-unneeded`. So, it not only contained `.debug_arranges`, `.debug_info`, `.debug_abbrev`, `.debug_line` and `.debug_str`, but also `.symtab` and `.strtab`. And the sizes of the sections were almost identical to their original sizes.

I've then tried to step-by-step debug all the three variants and haven't noticed any difference between them. Also I've produced crashes and core dumps with all of them and then tried to debug against the core dumps - also no difference.

Versions used:
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609
GNU objcopy (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1
GNU strip (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1