Stripping ELF binary but keeping symbols / source file locations information for gdb backtrace
I would like to strip an ELF binary compiled with debug information and keep only the minimal required information to provide symbols / source code location output in a GDB backtrace.
It would be binary post-processing to "downgrade" from -g to -g1.

[EDIT] To provide some context on this question (summary of the comments)
My product release build is actually a -g1 build.
The main reason is that the binary is running on customer’s premises and when it crashes, for lack of other logs/telemetry, support teams need access to basic debug information to assess/report issues to development teams.
I cannot ship full debug information (directly embedded or debuglink'ed) as they are too big (as in gigabytes) and it cannot be justified to clients (would be seen as waste), I cannot either request a network access opened to our internal debuginfod server for security reasons.
Our developers need full debug information to troubleshoot issues, but I can’t have a double build either.
Hence my question to "downgrade" a full debug build (-g) to a « limited » (-g1 like) debug one for shipping, while retaining full debug information internally, with a single build.

Consider this example C++ source file hello.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

static void *invalid_mem = (void *)1;

static void crash() {
  memset((char *)invalid_mem, 1, 100);
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  crash();
  return 0;
}

I compile it with debug information, run the produced hello binary to get a core file and print the backtrace with GDB:
$ g++ -g hello.cpp -o hello
$ ./hello
Hello World!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ gdb --quiet -ex bt -ex quit hello core
Reading symbols from hello...
[New LWP 479]
Core was generated by `./hello'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f16330982e0 in __memset_avx2_unaligned_erms () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#0  0x00007f16330982e0 in __memset_avx2_unaligned_erms () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00000000004011a3 in crash () at hello.cpp:7
#2  0x00000000004011cb in main () at hello.cpp:12

If I strip the debug information from the hello binary, I lose the source file location output in GDB but not the symbols since the .symtab section was not removed:
$ cp hello hello.full
$ objcopy --strip-debug hello.full hello
$ gdb --quiet -ex bt -ex quit hello core
Reading symbols from hello...
(No debugging symbols found in hello)
[New LWP 512]
Core was generated by `./hello'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007fc20289f2e0 in __memset_avx2_unaligned_erms () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#0  0x00007fc20289f2e0 in __memset_avx2_unaligned_erms () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00000000004011a3 in crash() ()
#2  0x00000000004011cb in main ()

According to the DWARF 4 standard specification (DWARF4 (pdf), the .debug_line section seems to be the one I need to keep but it does not seem to be enough:
$ objcopy --strip-debug --keep-section .debug_line hello.full hello
$ diff --color -Naur <(readelf -S hello.full | grep -oP '\.\K.[^ ]+') <(readelf -S hello | grep -oP '\.\K.[^ ]+')
--- /dev/fd/63  2024-04-29 12:23:49.023699848 +0200
+++ /dev/fd/62  2024-04-29 12:23:49.027699860 +0200
@@ -24,11 +24,7 @@
 bss
 comment
 gnu.build.a[...]
-debug_aranges
-debug_info
-debug_abbrev
 debug_line
-debug_str
 symtab
 strtab
 shstrtab
$ gdb --quiet -ex bt -ex quit hello core
Reading symbols from hello...
(No debugging symbols found in hello)
[New LWP 572]
Core was generated by `./hello'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f182a0462e0 in __memset_avx2_unaligned_erms () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#0  0x00007f182a0462e0 in __memset_avx2_unaligned_erms () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00000000004011a3 in crash() ()
#2  0x00000000004011cb in main ()

I have tried adding/removing individual .debug_* sections but it seems they are tied to .debug_info and nothing will work if this section is removed.
It would be even better if this could work with GDB's MiniDebugInfo to be able to fully strip the ELF binary and still get the symbols and source file location output in the GDB backtrace:
# Adding .gnu_debugdata section in binary for minidebuginfo  (see link)
$ gdb --quiet -ex bt -ex quit hello core
Reading symbols from hello...
Reading symbols from .gnu_debugdata for hello...
(No debugging symbols found in .gnu_debugdata for hello)
[New LWP 599]
Core was generated by `./hello'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f1de1f2d2e0 in __memset_avx2_unaligned_erms () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#0  0x00007f1de1f2d2e0 in __memset_avx2_unaligned_erms () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00000000004011a3 in crash() ()
#2  0x00000000004011cb in main ()

I know that I could use -g1 instead of -g but I need the full debug information (-g) that would be stripped and stored remotely while retaining minimal local debug information (-g1) in the binary.
Does anyone know if this is achievable?

Isn't something like separate info in '-dbgsym' packages? I.e. after building full hello with c++ -g hello.cpp -o hello put debug in a separate file anf link it objcopy --only-keep-debug hello hello.dbg; objcopy --strip-debug hello; objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=hello.dbg hello

Why not just leave the full debug info in the release binary? That'll make debugging easier and it won't slow down the program, it'll just take up a little extra disk space. It won't even make a big difference to a skilled person who wants to reverse engineer the program - they can do that anyway. Personally I always compile release builds with optimisation and full debug info enabled and ship that.

@JesperJuhl reasoning for "not leave" for example here https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2009/03/msg00228.html

@yvs2014, GDB will not print the backtrace I expect if this separate file is missing, which is not what I am after.

@JesperJuhl, in my use case the problem is that it's not just a little extra space but gigabytes of it. I cannot distribute full debug info because it's just too big and it would not be useful for clients anyway, just being seen as waste. Internally for our developers it's definitely required, but operators also like/need to have the minimal -g1 like debug information available to quickly raise support requests.

@aallrd "GDB will not print the backtrace" -- What do you mean under "not print"? backtrace if there's dbgsym file: #1  0x00005555555551aa in crash () at hello.cpp:7 #2  0x00005555555551e5 in main () at hello.cpp:12 and backtrace without that one #1  0x00005555555551aa in crash() () #2  0x00005555555551e5 in main ()

@yvs2014 If the debuglink'ed file is there yes, it will print the full expected backtrace. If the file is missing it won't, and that's not what I am after.

@aallrd in case of the product (for windows) I am working on, we simply request a crash dump from the customer. The binaries are built with separate debug Infos. I.e. we get the binaries + separate pdb debug files from the build. The pdb files are never shipped to the customer. When receiving the crash dump, we can open it in a debugger and point it to the pdbs and the correct source code commit. This allows us to inspect the call stack and variables etc (that aren't optimized out). But again, this is on Windows with msvc. I don't know about other OSs.

Ok, just searched for it and it seems possible to extract the debug symbols into a separate file also on *nix environments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/866731/3740047

This isn't a full answer so I'll only post as a comment here, @aallrd. To print function names in backtraces, GDB doesn't look at source code line. Lines are only used when in the CLI or TUI, for developer convenience. We find the function by matching the current PC to PC ranged defined bt DW_AT_low_pc and DW_AT_high_pc, attributes of the DW_TAG_subprogram. TL;DR, in theory you only need .debug_info sections, but .debug_abbrev includes information for opcodes in .debug_info that GDB might need, and .debug_str may include the actual function names, so better to keep them too

According to the man page for obj-copy, after compiling and linking as usual, you should —
Assuming your output (executable) file is called hello— :
objcopy --only-keep-debug hello hello.dbg

Which will create a file hello.dbg containing everything that would be stripped by --strip-debug.
Then
objcopy --strip-debug hello

Which will strip the debug info.
Finally:
objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=hello.dbg hello

Which will, as it would suggest, creates a .gnu_debuglink section which contains a reference to hello.dbg and adds it to the output file.

Alternatively (Compile hello.cpp to the hello elf, then):
cp hello hello.full #Create a copy of `hello` called `hello.full`
objcopy --strip-debug hello
objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=hello.full hello

Using the unstripped/full executable works with --add-gnu-debuglink, too!
I've read the question again (Checking links, this time. It's Friday night… I'm only human), and it appears that you know all of that… I don't get the question… You want to know where in the source FILE the bug is located in a release build? I don't get it, I'm sorry. There goes my Sunday, I guess (edit pending).

For various reasons, my product release build is actually a -g1 build. The main reason is that the binary is running on customer’s premises and when it crashes, for lack of other telemetry, support teams need access to basic debug information to assess/report issues to development teams. I cannot ship full debug information as they are too big and it cannot be justified to clients, but developers need it and I can’t have a double build either, hence my question to « dowgrade » a full debug build to a « limited » (-g1 like) debug one.

I've looked into it and I'm still not quite sure how to do it with a single build…

A coredump produced by a stripped binary perfectly fits the unstripped binary, too.
That gives a very simple solution that I have been applying for years:

Archive the unstripped binaries.
Deliver completely stripped binaries.

When you get a coredump from the customer, you can debug it with the unstripped binary as the source for the debug symbols as if the coredump had been created by the unstripped binary.

Thank you for the suggestion, but I need operators to have access to g1 like debug information on premise (symbols + source location). Having to retrieve the coredump from the customer to access this information is not acceptable in my situation.
